# With foreign keys automagically dropping out, can I set up an alert?

Tags: oracle, foreign-key, alerts

A strange thing happened to my company's Oracle database:

> Foreign key constraints keep dropping out by themselves.

If you could solve this problem, that would be great. But even if you can't, another method would be great, that is,

> Setting up an alert that will send an email when a foreign key constraint is dropped.

If you could solve any of the above 2 problems, it would be great to me.

Answer (score 1):

> Foreign keys kept dropping out by themselves.

Unless there is a *major* bug (and that would be talked about a lot online) in the version you are running, then this should not happen. *Something* is asking for the keys to be dropped rather than the engine doing it automatically.

> Setting up an alert that will send an email when a foreign key is dropped.

You could use a DDL trigger (search the documentation for "DDL Trigger", on online more generally for examples) to log the exact time that a `DROP` statement takes action. I don't know if sending mail is possible/practical in Orcale but you can definitely log the events to a table that you can refer to later.

The trigger may give you access to the user account that is used, though this may not be useful if it is being caused by an application user rather than a more specific login (i.e. a human admin). Knowing the exact time will allow you to more easily work out what process (an errant index maintenance script, someone deploying updates that are incorrect and reset the table's keys to an older incorrect setup, and so on) is asking for the keys to be dropped.

Comment: Is it possible to have a "global" trigger, such that whenever a foreign key drops, no matter in which table, the trigger will fire?

Comment: That is how DDL triggers work. They get called whenever a DDL event happens on the schema or whole database.

Comment: Instead of a DDL Trigger, you can just "cache" all Foreign Keys from the DBA_OBJECTS into a table.  Then run a script hourly to check the current DBA_OBJECT table/view to the "cached" table and alert for differences. (Edited for ORACLE vs. SQL Server)

Comment: @MguerraTorres: Polling that way is going to be less effective. You are scanning regularly instead of just waiting for an event (a trigger does nothing until called), and if you poll hourly you only know that a change happened in the last hour (with DDL trigger based logging you know the exact time the operation completed and *may* (depending on how your db user authentication is managed) know which user and/or application took the action that resulted in the change.

Comment: @DavidSpillett you make a great point.  DDL triggers don’t fire as often anyway, so it’s not hurting performance much.  Thanks for the insight!

Comment: I created a database-level after-drop trigger. But it worked only on table drops, but not on foreign key drops. How to write the trigger exactly?

Comment: I'm a SQL Server person mainly so can't help in detail. Examples that come up searching for `"DDL trigger" oracle` suggest key drops should call the trigger. You might be better to ask this as a new specific question (be sure to include the code you have tried so far, as that would help a passing Oracle expert to see if you have been hit by an "obvious"/common gotcha). One thought springs to mind though: if you drop the parent table then the implied key drop may not fire the trigger separately - are your users dropping and recreating whole tables, missing the keys when recreating?